# Can div's inside a section tag be appended dynamically so they appear inside the section tag?

Tags: javascript

I would like to be able to add (append) another set of div's to the section tag below when a user clicks on a button. For example adding the following div's:

```
    <div class="from-me">
      <p>this looks great. </p>
    </div>


<section>
    <div class="from-me">
      <p>Hey there! What's up?</p>
    </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="from-them">
      <p>Checking out iOS7 you know..</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

What I am trying to create is something similar to a text conversation for an e-learning project. I've had success creating a new div with a javascript function that is run by clicking a button, but I couldn't get it to append inside the section tag. Is this possible or do I need to approach this differently?

Thanks.

-Shawn

Comment: Could you please add the javascript that you have tried so far to your question?

Comment: Sure, it's possible. Why don't you show us the code you used to create a new div by clicking a button? Basically, you need to get a reference to your `section` and use [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) to append it.

Comment: He can't show us what he tried because that would have required him to actually do a search and run smack dab into thousands of results on how to do this. Instead he just asks us here to do it for him.

Comment: `Is this possible` - yes. `do I need to approach this differently` - don't know, show us your approach.

Comment: I found the sample code I sent here: https://codepen.io/samuelkraft/pen/Farhl

Comment: Here is the code I used to append the div's.<script>
function addDiv() {
    var objTo = document.getElementById('htmlextension2anc')
    var divtest = document.createElement('div');
    divtest.innerHTML = "new div"
    objTo.appendChild(divtest)
}
</script> The button had this code to run the function:addDiv(); I use a program called Lectora which has html extensions for users to add their own code. What I am trying to do is have a scrolling window in which the faked text conversion can take place. Everytime a button is clicked , text would be added to the window.